# Implementing webhook from a sub app in node.js

Tags: node.js

I have to implement a platform using Node.js where a file should be obtained from some other site using the webhook. But I could not find a site with the required features. So, I have to create another app to run in the background which have to send files at a regular interval. Those files should reach the platform by using the webhook. I don't know how to implement this scenario. Any suggestions?